# How to make my Django API public, which is connected to MYSQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, api, pythonanywhere

The problem is I have connected my Django API to MYSQL workbench, but it is only accessible in my localhost. Methods I have tried:

1. Forwarding a port and running my server with "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000".
2. I hosted my Django API in PythonAnywhere. Now my API became public, but I could not connect my Django API with MYSQL workbench

Please help me with it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the API is hosted on PythonAnywhere, then the code tries to connect to your local / server hosted mysql from the PythonAnywhere servers. You need to configure your network and mysql to accept remote connections from PythonAnywhere servers, although such code will likely to be slow and the security not particularly great - unless you can establish encrypted connection / tunnel to your systems.

Comment: I tried enabling remote connection in MYSQL, but still, PythonAnyhwere is not able to connect to MYSQL workbench.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you really cannot expect us to help you based on "I tried, but it does not work"! You need to be provide us with the exact error and the description of what you have done.

Comment: you won't be able to easily connect to a MySQL server on your local mcahine

Comment: Thanks, Shadow, and Conrad. I resolved my error using the first method that I mentioned. My windows firewall was only blocking all the connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly give access to mysql port 3306 from firewall, means create inbound rule for private and network.

if you are using windows,

go to firewall advance settings,

create a new inbound rule with port 3306,

give access to private network for now.

then create user in mysql and give access to your 0.0.0.0 ip by using this command:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'0.0.0.0' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

or

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'<your ipv4 address>' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

now you can get access from your machine and other into the mysql.

and i don't know how to give access in ubuntu.